# Using arduino mega is making my cnc claw buggy. Help

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I have three nema 23 steppers with one 8 channel relay(all the pins used) powering two dc motors and 4 IR sensors for feedback on the machine.

The problem is my machine is working fine for only 2 to 3 minutes until it just resets itself in the middle of the routine and crashes my whole system.

I am using 1/2 step microstepping with TB6600 stepper driver.
Also my arduino is mega 2560, maybe thats the problem I don't know about.

[image: Schematic]

Here I am attaching the code

```
const int dirPin1=2;
const int stepPin1=3;
const int dirPin2=4;
const int stepPin2=5;
const int dirPin3=6;
const int stepPin3=7; 
int del=1;
void setup() {
 pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
pinMode(14,OUTPUT);
pinMode(15,OUTPUT);
pinMode(16,INPUT);
pinMode(17,INPUT);
pinMode(18,INPUT);
pinMode(19,INPUT);
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
 
}
void picker_up(){
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  delay(570);
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  delay(100);
}
void picker_down(){
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  delay(320);
  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(11,HIGH);
  delay(100);
}
void claw_close(){
  digitalWrite(12,LOW);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  delay(100);
}
void claw_open(){
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,LOW);
  digitalWrite(15,LOW);
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(14,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(15,HIGH);
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
digitalWrite(dirPin1,HIGH);
digitalWrite(dirPin2,HIGH);
digitalWrite(dirPin3,LOW);
for(int i=0;i<=1200;i++){
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stepPin2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stepPin3,HIGH);
  delay(del);
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin3,LOW);
  delay(del);
}
for(int i=1;i<=400;i++){
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
  delay(del);
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
  delay(del);
}
delay(1000);
picker_down();
claw_open();
claw_close();
picker_up();
delay(2000);
digitalWrite(dirPin1,LOW);
digitalWrite(dirPin2,LOW);
digitalWrite(dirPin3,HIGH);
for(int i=1;i<=400;i++){
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
  delay(del);
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
  delay(del);
}
for(int i=0;i<=1200;i++){
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stepPin2,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(stepPin3,HIGH);
  delay(del);
  digitalWrite(stepPin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(stepPin3,LOW);
  delay(del);
}
delay(2000);
}
```

I am not getting why this is happening. Or do I need some more electronic components  included in the machine and I know I could have used mosfets to control the motors but I am just way too lazy.

I used uno before this and it used to work fine, so should I just go back to using it?

Also I have modified the code to be compatible with the uno again so please bare with the pin numbers.

Comment: I don't believe there's any reasonable way to answer the question with the information provided. It could be literally anything. I would not recommend doing stepper driving "by hand" when there are libraries available. At the *very* least you'd need to include a schematic.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb here with no schematic, but a common reason for resetting is low voltage caused by too much current draw. "I know I could have used mosfets to control the motors but I am just way to lazy." suggests a possible cause. Are your motors powered through the Arduino?

Comment: I am using external power sources for everything even the relay is not powered by the arduino mega

Comment: add some debugging code

Comment: Still not much to go on (this is a block diagram, not a schematic). Since there's essentially no code other than digital writes, I would suspect an electrical problem.

Comment: I actually thought of using a stepper motor library but the library accelstepper blocks every other actuator to make the stepper rotate which means my two motors that are running together will not work.
@DaveNewton

Comment: Non AccelStepper is not blocking. You just have to use it right by setting the target position and then execute the `run` function of the corresponding accelstepper objects very regularily and fast, so that they don't miss a step. Actually the library is meant for that. It also has a blocking function, but more for completeness and special situations. The non-blocking way is actually the intended way of use

Comment: I actually kind of figured out the problem on my own till now and it is related to using the relay to power my motors as arduino is not able to handle the relay switching so I am using a slave arduino to not mess up the the system.

Comment: If you solved the problem ypu can write an answer to your own question. That way your oearninga might help others in the future

Comment: Ok so first of all I ditched the 12 volt and 5 volt motor(this one was a hacked tower pro servo) and used two pneumatic cylinders as I happen to have compression engines in my firm to make the actuator. While now its more rugged but better. I also had solved the problem I asked about, this was done by using a slave arduino nano so I just made the use of serial communication to fire the relay subroutine onto the nano this way even if my relay throw some errors nothing would go wrong with my system. Also another mistake I did was power up the relay and motor together.